# Import 3D imaging data in xBim

Tags: revit, ifc, bim, xbim

Is there is any way to Import 3D imaging data (point clouds and/or other similar 3D imaging products - specify formats supported) into xBim files?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to save point clouds in IFC files?

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: Would you please clarify exactly what type of geometry you have and what you expect to get?

Comment: I want to know if I can import point clouds or any other 3D formats(other than ifc) using xbim libs like import in revit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, xBIM reads and writes only IFC files - STEP and XML. You will need another library specifically suited for your file format.